# Non-standard tags effects on SEO

Tags: seo, html5, standards

I am interested in understanding the effects on SEO (not only Google) of non standard HTML elements, be they [HTMLUnknownElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLUnknownElement) or [Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components/Using_custom_elements) while retaining as much as possible native semantic HTML tags, and how much these effects are likely to change in the future.

Please note that the question is related to HTMLUnknownElement or Custom Elements only, not to shadow DOM and [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_components). For Web Components [this document](https://medium.com/patternfly-elements/web-components-and-seo-58227413e072) well explains the effects on different search engines, but here there is no relevant javascript DOM layout or content generation involved, no slots or templates.

Say we have this HTML code:

```
<div>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h1>My SEO title</h1>
      <div>
        <!-- contents -->
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>

</div>
```

Is it worse, from a SEO point of view, this version, and how much?

```
<htmlunknownelement>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h1>My SEO title</h1>
      <div>
        <!-- contents -->
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>

</htmlunknownelement>
```

And this version?

```
<!-- Custom elements / Web components -->
<custom-element>

  <section>
    <article>
      <h1>My SEO title</h1>
      <div>
        <!-- contents -->
      </div>
    </article>
  </section>

</custom-element>
```

Is for example the h1 tag ignored, or less weighted, by SEO when inside a non-standard HTML element?
And what if the non-standard element is inside the h1 instead of wrapping it?

Any link to technical documentation on this would be appreciated.